# Encore heureux / Encore heureuse

Tags: expressions, genre

Je souhaiterais savoir si l'expression « Encore heureux » peut s'accorder avec le sujet s'il est féminin ! Est-ce qu'une femme peut dire : « Encore heureuse » dans le contexte suivant ?

> ─ Le fils: Maman est-ce que je peux regarder la télé après 22h.
>   ─ La maman: Non, il n'en est pas question
>   ─ Le fils: mais maman, j'ai fait tous mes devoirs
>   ─ La maman: Encore heureux !

La question, en fait, c'est quel est le sens de *Encore heureux* ? Est-ce que c'est « C'est encore heureux » ou bien « Je suis encore heureux » ?

Le problème c'est que tout penche vers le premier sens, mais je n'arrive pas à le trouver dans une source référence. Merci d'apporter une réponse avec arguments s'il vous plait.

Answer (score 5):

Si on développait l'expression « encore heureux » pour y introduire un sujet et un verbe, ce serait une forme impersonnelle telle que :

> C'est encore heureux !

« c'» représentant le fait qui vient d'être énoncé ou qui va être énoncé, par exemple :

> J'ai raté le bus et j'ai dû rentrer à pied, (c'est/il est) encore heureux qu'il ne pleuvait pas.

Que dans cette phrase on mette « elle » ou « ils » à la place de « je », l'expression « c'est encore/il est encore heureux » reste invariable. « c'/il » représente « qu'il ne pleuvait pas ».

> ─  Est-ce que je peux regarder la télé, j'ai fait tous mes devoirs ?
>
> ─  Encore heureux (que tu aies fait tous tes devoirs) !

Le *Dictionnaire historique en la langue française* (s.l.d. Alain Rey) dit que « encore heureux » est une forme elliptique de « c'est heureux ».  Le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/heureux)  présente « encore heureux » comme la forme populaire et familière avec ellipse du verbe *être* de  *C'est heureux*/ *il est heureux que*.

Si tu ne veux dire que c'est la mère qui est heureuse tu es obligé d'exprimer le sujet et le verbe :

> ─  Est-ce que je peux regarder la télé, j'ai fait tous mes devoirs ?
> ─  J'en suis heureuse mais c'est non quand même.

Imaginons maintenant le cas limite où la mère, se contente de répondre avec un seul mot : « Heureux ! »
→ On interpréterait : « C'est heureux ! » (C'est une bonne chose)

ou : « Heureuse ! »
→ On interpréterait :  « J'en suis heureuse »

Imaginons que la mère réponde :

> Encore heureuse !

Ce n'est pas totalement impossible, mais ça implique que la mère se réjouit de son bonheur et qu'elle est un nouvelle fois heureuse (de l'attitude de son fils par exemple). Et ce serait dit avec le ton adéquat et insistant sur « heureux ».  Ça n'a plus rien à voir avec l'expression « encore heureux » qui exprime le soulagement.

Comment: Etes-vous sûre que c'est une forme impersonnelle ? Autrement dit, pouvez-vous ajouter un lien qui le décrit formellement SVP ? J'ai toujours vu l'expression "encore heureux" comme une opinion personnelle du locuteur ("[j'en suis] encore heureux") , même si en y repensant ça n'a pas vraiment de sens.

Comment: @A.L Bien sûr que celui qui dit *Encore heureux*  exprime, comme vous dites, « une opinion personnelle » et je ne vois pas comment il en serait autrement ; ce qui est heureux pour moi, ne l'est pas forcément pour tout le monde. En disant *c'est dommage* il exprimerait une opinion personnelle opposée mais qui s'exprime grammaticalement de façon tout aussi impersonnelle. J'ai ajouté dans ma réponse deux références qui ont la réputation d'être sérieuses. On peut signaler l'expression dans d'autres langues (*it's lucky* *y menos mal que* *ein Glück*) où le locuteur n'est pas le sujet grammatical.